# Apache: Conditional SSLCertificateFile depending on domain?

Tags: apache, https, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am running a multi-language web store accessible from differents domains, that lead to different languages.

The apache configuration is quite complex and I would like to have one single file shared with all the stores. I had this in place until I had to introduce SSL.
When it comes to apache and SSL certificates I would need to do something like:

```
SetEnv is_es 0<br>
SetEnvIfNoCase Host .*es is_es 1<br>
SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/spanish.server.crt env=is_es<br>
```

This is aparently not possible, apache tells me:

```
 <i>SSLCertificateFile takes one argument, SSL Server Certificate file (`/path/to/file' - PEM or DER encoded)</i>
```

I was wondering if there is any workaround. My goal is to avoid having different copies of the same configuration and having to propagate manually any changes I want to make.
It is hosted on a dedicated server, so I am free to do any changes to the setup.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, when you use Server Name Indication (SNI), which you'll almost certainly need here, the configuration is done per VirtualHost dispatched using its ServerName.

Answer (score 1):

When you are on a https connection, the Host header is inside the SSL encapsulation, so you need the full SSL handshake before you check for an hostname for your virtualhost.

You should go for SSL certificates with [SAN (Subject Alternative Names)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4985.txt), this will allow that a single certificate for multiple hostnames. (or a wildcard cert)

All the main browsers supports it already:

- http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name-compatibility.htm

And you can get one of this certs from the majors CAs:

- http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm
- http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/subject-alternative-name-certificates/index.html
- http://www.thawte.com/ssl/san-uc-ssl-certificates/index.html

Comment: Thanks Marcelo. The answer totally makes sense and has a great workaround. Kudos!

Comment: @jeanlucorsai, I was assuming you already had (and needed) multiple certificates, in which case you would also have needed SNI (or multiple IP addresses), but multiple SANs should work indeed, in a single certificate.